# scrollIntoView() doesn't work after opening collapsible

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, js-scrollintoview

When I use `scrollIntoView()` normally to scroll to a selected element on the page, it works great.

But what I want to do, is click a button that opens a collapsible (thus making the page taller), and then `scrollIntoView()` to the top of that collapsible element.

When I try adding that piece of functionality, upon the first click the scrolling just "jerks" or flickers a bit, and on the second click it scrolls to the middle of the collapsible.

How can I get around this?

I've tried performing `scrollIntoView()` after a delay of 10 seconds, same bad behavior occurs.

Sorry, can't share the code because it doesn't belong to me.

Comment: are you animating the collapsible? maybe try calling scrollIntoView after the animation is complete

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @YarGnawh. i did try it with setTimeout with a delay of 10 seconds :(. i will edit answer to include that info.

Comment: It's really hard to help without seeing some code.  Certainly you can extract some of the code and by doing so may even find the bug.  And then I would serve the same purpose as a rubber duck.